# How to write an array to a file?

Tags: arrays, powershell-2.0, cpu-usage

I try to write a short script what will count average value for CPU for last XY minutes.

I wrote something like that (just short overview). First part of the script just stored values in tmp file. From this values is count avg value:

```
$CPU= ........ Add-Content "myfile.txt" "$CPU"
$array=(Get-Content -Path myfile.txt);
$AVG=($array | Measure-Object -Average).average;
```

Then I set *first-in first-out* function:

```
if ($array.length -gt XY) {$array=($array[1..($array.Length-0)])>myfile.txt}.
```

When this condition is completed next execution write to script "strange" character and not number. Type command report "?" as last character in file instead number so average function don`t know work with it.

It doesn't work for PowerShell version 2. I don't have such issue in version 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"FIFO" snippet :

```
(get-content c:\temp\test.txt)  |select -skip 1 | set-content c:\temp\test.txt
```